# dotnet core Http Response Header Content-Type lost

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a WebApi server solution that includes .Net Core 2.0.

First, I was define special case of error use HttpStatusCode 550.

In case of nomally that is HttpStatusCode 200 that is included with "Content-Type:application/json" in response header.

By the way, In case of HttpStatusCode 550 that is not included with "Content-Type:application/json" in response header.

This is true even if I create the middleware in the solution and do the following:

Invoking in PostMan that will result in a Json format case of HttpStatusCode 200. 
But, it is not json format on HttpStatusCode 550.
So, that is broken Korean language in this case.

Append, that is no problem in local windows 10 machine & ubuntu 16.0.4 machine,
It just raise in server machine in ubuntu 16.0.4.

Is there a way to solve it?

## [Startup.cs]

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
        });

        // CORS Middleware
        app.UseMiddleware<HttpMiddleware>();
        app.UseMvc();
}
```

## [HttpMiddleware.cs]

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        await _next(context);
}
```

In addition, I set the result value as below.

## [myControll.cs]

```
errorresult _errorresult = new errorresult();
JsonResult _ObjectResult;

try
{
    :

    [ source code ]

    :

    // success case
    // _product is result object
    _product.resultcode = "200";
    _product.resultmessage = _CommonLogic.GetResponseMessage(_PurchaseMessage);
    _product.resultoptional = "";
    _product.processtime = Convert.ToString(_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    _stopwatch.Stop();
    _ObjectResult = _CommonLogic.GetObjectResult(_product, 200);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _errorresult = new errorresult();
    _errorresult.resultcode = "550";
    _errorresult.resultmessage = ex.Message.ToString();
    _errorresult.resultoptional = "";
    _errorresult.processtime = Convert.ToString(_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    _stopwatch.Stop();
    _ObjectResult = _CommonLogic.GetObjectResult(_errorresult, 550);
}
```

## [CommonLogic.cs]

```
    public JsonResult GetObjectResult(object obj,int iStatusCode)
    {
        JsonResult _ObjectResult = new JsonResult(obj);
        _ObjectResult.StatusCode = iStatusCode;
        // _ObjectResult.ContentTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json; charset=utf-8"));
        // _ObjectResult.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        return _ObjectResult;
    }
```

Thanks for reading of my problem.

Comment: Why are you setting content type twice?

Comment: It just test. :) ... i just use last code ==> "context.Response.Headers.Add ("Content-Type", "application / json");" , But, It can't wokrs so i tested first line code. :(

Comment: Remove the second one, it may throw

Comment: yep. i remove that. and re-try test. but it can't wokrs yet. :(  .. do i try another method ? thanks.

Comment: is `HttpMiddleware ` the first middleware in the pipeline? If not, please show the whole `Configure` method

Comment: i'm sorry, update my source... :)